# C++ cout with prefix

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, ostream

I want a ostream with a prefix at the beginning of every line redirected on cout;
I try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
class parallel_cout : public std::ostream
{
public:
parallel_cout(std::ostream& o):out(o){}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (const T& val)
{
    out << "prefix " << val;
    return *this;
}

std::ostream& out;

};

int main()
{
 parallel_cout pc(std::cout);
 pc<<"a\nb"<<"c\n";
}
```

but i have in output

```
prefix a
b
```

without c. why this?

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to derive from std::stream - it doesn't have a virtual destructor, and your code shows how output operations don't really work on the derived class, because you are returning a reference to the base class. I'll try to expand to a full answer, unless somebody beats me to it :)

Comment: Your template should return `parallel_cout&`, not generic `ostream&`.

Comment: @martin_pr `std::ostream` has a virtual constructor (inherited from `std::ios_base`). Also, `std::fstream` and `std::stringstream` are also derived classes, but they work fine. The main reason why you would want to derive from a IOStreams base class is to wrap around a custom `std::streambuf`, which is what the concrete stream classes do.

Comment: @499602D2 Fair enough, my bad.

Comment: In fact, this code shouldn't even compile as `std::ostream` doesn't have a default-constructor and you haven't initialized it in the initializer list. On clang with [libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d059c7a2e4c9f840) you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Deduplicator you're right!thanks!it works..I have just problems with std::endl after << that makes no match for operator<< error

Comment: @volperossa: you should really **not** use the approach using templates! The use of manipulators like `std::endl` also won't be the end of your problems: when passing you stream to a function taking a `std::ostream&` it will also not do the Right Thing. Using a custom stream buffer _will_ do the Right Thing both for manipulators as well as when passing the stream stream to function taking an `std::ostream&`.

That said: the problem with manipulators is that they are function templates and `std::ostream` has a suitable output operator which is used to deduce the template arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you modify the behavior of `std::ostream` is **not** by overloading any of the output operators! Instead, you derive a class from `std::streambuf` and override the `virtual` functions `overflow()` and `sync()`. In you case you'd probably create a filtering stream buffer, i.e., you'd take another `std::streambuf` as argument and write a somehow modified stream of characters to this stream buffer.

Here is a quick example:

```
#include <iostream>

class prefixbuf
    : public std::streambuf
{
    std::string     prefix;
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    bool            need_prefix;

    int sync() {
        return this->sbuf->pubsync();
    }
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            if (this->need_prefix
                && !this->prefix.empty()
                && this->prefix.size() != this->sbuf->sputn(&this->prefix[0], this->prefix.size())) {
                return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
            }
            this->need_prefix = c == '\n';
        }
        return this->sbuf->sputc(c);
    }
public:
    prefixbuf(std::string const& prefix, std::streambuf* sbuf)
        : prefix(prefix)
        , sbuf(sbuf)
        , need_prefix(true) {
    }
};

class oprefixstream
    : private virtual prefixbuf
    , public std::ostream
{
public:
    oprefixstream(std::string const& prefix, std::ostream& out)
        : prefixbuf(prefix, out.rdbuf())
        , std::ios(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this))
        , std::ostream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this)) {
    }
};

int main()
{
    oprefixstream out("prefix: ", std::cout);
    out << "hello\n"
        << "world\n";
}
```

Stream buffers conceptually keep an internal buffer which is, however, not set up in the example above. Every time there is no space for a character to be written to the output buffer, the `virtual` function `overflow()` is called with a character (it may also be called with the special value `std::char_traits<char>::eof()` which is typically used to flush the buffer). Since there is no buffer, `overflow()` will be called for every character. All this function does is to see if it needs to write a prefix and, if so, writes the `prefix`. In case a newline `'\n'` is written, the function remembers that it needs to write the `prefix` if another character is written. It then just forwards writing of the character to the underlying stream buffer.

The `virtual` function `sync()` is used to *synchronize the stream with its external representation*. For a stream buffer keeping a buffer it makes sure that any buffer is written. Since the `prefixbuf` doesn't really keep a buffer, all it needs to is to delegate the `sync()` request to the underlying stream buffer by calling `pubsync()`.

Comment: I don't know about these methods (sync and overflow) do you know a good tutorial?

Comment: The IOStreams library is explained in Nicolai Josuttis's "The C++ Standard library" and, obviously, the explanation is _excellent_ (I may be bias, though, having written in particular the original version of the sections on creating stream buffers). There is also Angelika Langer and Klaus Kreft's "IOStreams and Locales" but this is an entire book just devoted to I/O. Otherwise, if you look on Google for "streambuf" and either "James Kanze" or "Dietmar Kuehl" you should find plenty of resources.

Comment: Dear Dietmar, what is the visibility class (`public`/`protected`/`private`) in the above examples? In Nicolai's book, the custom streambuffer example assigns `protected` to the `overflow` method and leaves out the sync.

Comment: @shuhalo: the `prefixbuf` isn’t intended to be inherited from. Thus, it doesn’t really matter whether `prefixbuf` is `protected` or `private`. When I wrote above code I was probably too lazy to put in `protected` before `overflow()`: if `prefixbuf` is inherited from for whatever reason it may be useful to make `prefixbuf::overflow()` accessible to the derived class. If I forget `sync()` in Nico’s book for a filtering stream buffer for output I made an error and NIco didn’t correct it when he integrated it into his book: on which example is that?

Comment: I have read Chapter 13.13.3 in "The C++ Standard library" prior to coming to this thread (21st printing, 2008). Hope this helps. Thanks for the quick reply by the way.

Comment: [example usage in a class](https://github.com/milahu/random/blob/master/cc/print-lines-with-prefix/main.cc)

Comment: fix warning: `(long unsigned int) this->sbuf->sputn`

Answer (score 3):

As Dietmar said, what you want is your own streambuf, something on this general order:

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <iostream>

class prefixer: public std::streambuf {
public:
    prefixer(std::streambuf* s): sbuf(s) {}
    ~prefixer() { overflow('\n'); }
private:
    typedef std::basic_string<char_type> string;

    int_type overflow(int_type c) {

        if (traits_type::eq_int_type(traits_type::eof(), c))
            return traits_type::not_eof(c);
        switch (c) {
        case '\n':
        case '\r':  {
            prefix = "[FIX]";
            buffer += c;
            if (buffer.size() > 1)
                sbuf->sputn(prefix.c_str(), prefix.size());
            int_type rc = sbuf->sputn(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());
            buffer.clear();
            return rc;
        }
        default:
            buffer += c;
            return c;
        }
    }

    std::string prefix;
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    string buffer;
};
```

To use this, you create an instance of it from some other streambuf (that defines where it's going to write to) and then (usually) create an ostream using this streambuf. Then you can write to that ostream, and your prefix gets written to each line of output. For example:

```
int main() { 
    prefixer buf(std::cout.rdbuf());

    std::ostream out(&buf);

    out << "Test\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice effort although I prefer my version: for one I think it is simpler and for another it doesn't create a trailing prefix after the last newline. It also prefixes the first line without a spurious newline. Finally, it passes through the flush to the underlying stream buffer. I realize that your version is buffered but without flushing upon `sync()` that's causing some harm. My version isn't buffered for simplicity although I realize that not buffering stream buffers introduces a potential performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could write a function though the syntax changes.

```
template<typename T>
void print(T content)
{
    cout<<whatever your prefix is;
    cout<<content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output operator is returning a reference to the base class (`std::ostream`), which means that the next call to `operator <<` will not use your implementation.

Changing your output operator to this should fix your problem:

```
template <typename T>
parallel_cout& operator<< (const T& val)
{
    out << "prefix " << val;
    return *this;
}
```